# To malloc or not to malloc, that is the question!

Tags: c, file, file-io, malloc

Do I need to malloc when creating a file to write to?

The file will be based on the contents of 2 others, so would I need to malloc space for the writeable file of `sizeof( file a ) + sizeof( file b) + 1`?

Sorry if this makes no sense; if it doesn't then I guess I need to go read some more :D

Essentially, I have 2 txt files and a string sequence - I am writing each line of each file side by side separated by the string sequence.

```
txt file a

hello stack over 
flow this 
is a test

txt file b

jump the
gun i am
a novice

seperator == xx

output ==

hello stack overxxjump the
flow thisxxgun i am
is a testxxa novice
```

Comment: text files or binary files? Are you merging 2 files ?

Comment: Your have to better state your purpose. Handling files does not necessarily involve using "malloc" and thus it depends on your actual use-case/purpose.

Comment: essentially, i have 2 txt files and a string sequence - i am writing each line of each file side by side seperated by the string sequence

Comment: I will gently suggest that you look at some of this material in K&R, it will be much clearer then.  (Hint: Start at the beginning, work your way up to this point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing it in order, can't you just use `fprintf()` or `fwrite()` whenever you need to write something out, instead of writing the entire file at once?

EDIT: Based on your update, here's basically what you have to do (probably not valid C since I'm not a C programmer):

EDIT2: With some help from msw:

```
const int BUFSIZE = 200;
FILE *firstFile = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
FILE *secondFile = fopen("file2.txt", "r");
FILE *outputFile = fopen("output.txt", "w");
char* seperator = "xx";
char firstLine[BUFSIZE], secondLine[BUFSIZE];

// start a loop here
fgets(firstLine, 200, firstFile);
fgets(secondLine, 200, secondFile);
// Remove '\n's from each line

fprintf(outputFile, "%s%s%s", firstLine, seperator, secondLine);
// end a loop here

fclose(outputFile);
fclose(firstFile);
fclose(secondFile);
```

Comment: I figured it would be more clear to put in what we're actually passing rather than numbers (since this way it's more clear that the 3rd argument is the size of each thing to read in).

Comment: It is idomatic to use `BUFSIZ` for a `char[]` of unknown length. I'd also use `fgets(char * buf, int size, FILE *f)` as it stops on newline (which would need to be chopped off). I know you aren't a C programmer so it's excusable ;)

Comment: Ahhhh I just deleted that section since I didn't know how to do it. I'll fix it now.

Comment: There are 2 caveats:


1. fgets reads the new-line character also. Thus, when printing
"%s%s%s" your aren't going to get it all in the same line.


2. In fact you will need one more loop to copy the remaining of the longest file to the output file

Answer (score 1):

You only need to `malloc` the entire size of a file if you need to hold the entire file in memory (and even then, you can probably use `mmap` or something instead). Allocate as much memory as you need for the *data* you intend to work with in memory: no more, no less.

Answer (score 0):

Files are on disk, malloc is for RAM.

You'd only malloc if you needed space in memory to store the data PRIOR to writing out to the file, otherwise, typically you'd use a stack allocated buffer of say 8k to write to the file in chunks.

So taking your question as-is, no you'd rarely malloc just to write to a file.

If your goal is to keep the file in memory in completion, then you'd malloc sizeof file.